# update query optimization postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

i m doing a migration of a data base from oracle to postgresql and i have got a performance problem with and update query.

```
explain  update airepp.EQP_CALC_STAT_EVENEMENT e  set EVT_COM_POPULATION=(
        SELECT    f.COM_RECENSEMENT_DER_POPULATION
        FROM      airepp.EQP_FOURNISSEUR f where e.EVT_LIEU_LOC_CODE = f.COM_CODE)
     ;
```

in oracle this query takes about 5 minutes and in postgresql it takes 55 minutes, they have the same indexes with the exact fields, this is the explain of postgresql and oracle of this query

[image: explain postgresql]

Oracle plan:

[image: explain oracle]

I have tried this but it was worse in 66 minutes

```
explain update airepp.EQP_CALC_STAT_EVENEMENT e
    set EVT_COM_POPULATION = f.COM_RECENSEMENT_DER_POPULATION    
    FROM airepp.EQP_FOURNISSEUR f 
    where e.EVT_LIEU_LOC_CODE = f.COM_CODE;
```

is there any other way to write this query in a more optimized way to have the same results of oracle or near?

Comment: What is the cardinality of your reference table? 37 millions of index scan is not what looks good in any database.

Comment: how to see it ?

Comment: Are you sure your two databases have the same data? *(You don't have one with 40M rows and one with 10M rows?)* and that you have the same hardware and configuration?  *(You don't have spinning discs on one, and SSDs on the other, or partitioning being different, or log files on different drives, differences in CPU or Memory, etc, etc, etc, etc.)*  You may need to ask your DBA to give a full resource description of each server.

Comment: they are the exact  same dbs with the same ressources

Comment: @astentx actually the postgresql table contains 36 m against 10 m in oracle but can that explain 55 minutes of execution time in postgresql beside 5 minutes in oracle ?

Comment: @loup93 . . . You are updating *all* rows in a table with 40 million rows.  I would look for some alternative way of doing what you want -- such as using a view to access the value rather than storing it in a table.

Comment: it updates only 6 rows . .not all the table of corse i have a where clause there

Comment: The where clause you show is on the subquery, and doesn't prevent all rows from being updated.  Maybe you should suppress degenerate updates.

Comment: i talk about this : explain update airepp.EQP_CALC_STAT_EVENEMENT e
    set EVT_COM_POPULATION = f.COM_RECENSEMENT_DER_POPULATION    
    FROM airepp.EQP_FOURNISSEUR f 
    where e.EVT_LIEU_LOC_CODE = f.COM_CODE;

Answer (score 0):

You may face this problem because of large amount of lookups. For reference table with cardinality much smaller than main table you can try to use `update ... from...` which can leverage hash join.

Here is the example:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select v::text as some_code, random() as some_value
> from generate_series(1, 20000) as v
>
> create unique index t_idx on t(some_code)
>
> create table t_big
> as
> select
>   v as id,
>   trunc(v / 10)::text as some_code,
>   null as some_value
> from generate_series(1, 100000) v
> ```

> ```
> explain analyze
> update t_big
> set some_value = t.some_value
> from t
> where t_big.some_code = t.some_code
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                              |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Update on t_big  (cost=559.00..1885.53 rows=45135 width=80) (actual time=3908.306..3908.309 rows=0 loops=1)             |
> |   ->  Hash Join  (cost=559.00..1885.53 rows=45135 width=80) (actual time=7.715..1709.967 rows=99991 loops=1)            |
> |         Hash Cond: (t_big.some_code = t.some_code)                                                                      |
> |         ->  Seq Scan on t_big  (cost=0.00..982.35 rows=45135 width=42) (actual time=0.048..390.277 rows=100000 loops=1) |
> |         ->  Hash  (cost=309.00..309.00 rows=20000 width=46) (actual time=7.564..7.565 rows=20000 loops=1)               |
> |               Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1261kB                                                          |
> |               ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..309.00 rows=20000 width=46) (actual time=0.017..3.439 rows=20000 loops=1)  |
> | Planning Time: 0.678 ms                                                                                                 |
> | Execution Time: 3908.437 ms                                                                                             |
> ```

> ```
> explain analyze
> update t_big
> set some_value = (
>   select some_value from t where t.some_code = t_big.some_code
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                 |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Update on t_big  (cost=0.00..1054578.00 rows=126600 width=46) (actual time=7759.679..7759.680 rows=0 loops=1)              |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on t_big  (cost=0.00..1054578.00 rows=126600 width=46) (actual time=0.086..5146.080 rows=100000 loops=1)    |
> |         SubPlan 1                                                                                                          |
> |           ->  Index Scan using t_idx on t  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=100000) |
> |                 Index Cond: (some_code = t_big.some_code)                                                                  |
> | Planning Time: 0.217 ms                                                                                                    |
> | Execution Time: 7759.737 ms                                                                                                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=116e6f33e2d918015617c4e4358e9d07)*

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, but i have tried the query with join its takes more time to be executed ... in my case